# Error "El servidor host de Docker está configurado para "Linux"; sin embargo, el proyecto está destinado para "Window". Windows containers no funciona

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

Estoy intentando contenerizar una aplicación ASP .NET Mi máquina tiene la edición Enterprise de Windows 11.

La aplicación es un proxy simple con un Dockerfile:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker} .

y un archivo docker-compose.yml:

version: '3.4'

services:
wke.documentconverter.webservice:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}wkedocumentconverterwebservice
build:
context: .\WebService
dockerfile: Dockerfile

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2022. Al intentar ejecutar la aplicación utilizando la opción "Contenedor (Dockerfile)", me encuentro con la siguiente salida:

"El servidor host de Docker está configurado para "Linux"; sin embargo, el proyecto está destinado para "Windows"."

Cambiar a contenedores de Windows parece la solución más sencilla, pero no funciona. Si lo hago, Docker Desktop se queda en bucle infinito. Si lo cierro y vuelvo abrir, se queda de nuevo cargando infinitamente. Tengo que desinstalar la aplicación y volver a instalarla para utilizarla.

Después de eso, intenté compilar la aplicación en la línea de comandos para ver si obtenía más información sobre el problema. Cuando ejecuto *docker-compose build* en la carpeta de mi aplicación, obtengo el siguiente error:

**failed to solve: failed to register layer: link /Files/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/System/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui: no such file or directory**

He comprobado que en mi máquina existen ya ambos archivos. Intenté buscar ese error en Google pero no encontré nada, excepto [esto](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/370). El mismo error pero para *InkObj.dll.mui* (y otra ruta, pero similar). Sin embargo, si se desplazan al final de la página web, verán que la persona resolvió el problema cambiando a contenedores de Windows (lo que no funcionó para mí).

Intenté buscar una solución pero no encontré nada...

MÁS INFORMACIÓN

En Docker Desktop, dentro de Configuración -> Constructores tengo tanto desktop-linux como desktop-windows (además del predeterminado). Desktop-linux funciona bien pero en Desktop-windows obtengo el siguiente error:

**Error del constructor: la solicitud devolvió un error interno del servidor para la ruta de API y versión http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopWindowsEngine/_ping, compruebe si el servidor admite la versión de API solicitada.**

También vi [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976644/your-docker-server-host-is-configured-for-linux-however-your-project-targets) publicación y en *Container.targets* comprobé la variable *$(DockerTargetOs)* (porque *$(DockerDefaultTargetOS)'* no existía) y ya apuntaba a Linux...

Si alguien puede darme algún consejo o alguna posible solución, bienvenido sea.